# Generics in construct: Java does not recognize that my own class implements an interface

Tags: java, generics

I want to instantiate a new java `ThreadPoolExecutor` with this piece of code:

```
public class ImageList {
    private LinkedBlockingQueue<Image> list;
    private final ThreadPoolExecutor executor;

    public ImageList() {
        executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(2, 4, 100, TimeUnit.SECONDS, list);
    }
}
```

Where `Image` has the following header:

```
public class Image implements Runnable, Serializable
```

However, Java complains that a constructor for the type `BlockingQueue<Runnable>` was not found. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Inheritance in Generics is little different from Inheritance in classes. You need to use wildcards http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html

Comment: Generics and polymorphism: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructor expects a `BlockingQueue<Runnable>`. You pass it a `BlockingQueue<Image>`.

A `BlockingQueue<Image>` is not a `BlockingQueue<Runnable>`. Indeed, you may store any kind of Runnable in a `BlockingQueue<Runnable>`, but you may only store `Image` instances in a `BlockingQueue<Image>`.

If it were, you could do the following:

```
BlockingQueue<Image> list = new BlockingQueue<Image>();
BlockingQueue<Runnable> list2 = list1;
list2.add(new Runnable() {...});
```

and boom! your `BlockingQueue<Image>` would contain something other than an `Image`.

Comment: Wouldn't you be able to do `BlockingQueue<? extends Runnable>`?

Comment: No. The thread pool needs a BlockingQueue<Runnable>, to be able to store the Runnable instances it creates in the queue. BlockingQueue<? extends Runnable> means: BlockingQueue of some unknown subclass which is or extends Runnable. You can't store anything into such a queue.

Comment: Doesn't `Image` implement ("extends") `Runnable` though? So you could put `Image`s into `BlockingQueue<? extends Runnable>`, or am I wrong (or misunderstanding OP's question)?

Comment: You're wrong. Read my answer: it should answer your question: `BlockingQueue<? extends Runnable> list = new BlockingQueue<Image>();BlockingQueue<Runnable> list2 = list1;list2.add(new Runnable() {...});// boom!`

Comment: You are right. That would only work if you could change the constructor. Constructor expects a queue of `Runnable`. But queue of `Runnable` is not a queue of `Image`. Thanks.

Comment: Wildcarded instances inherently have issues with adding things to them as @JB Niznet stated.  The ? syntax does not mean any instance of Runnable.  It indicates that it's a homogenious instance that's type compatible.  So BlockingQueue<? extends Runnable> doesn't mean that i have a queue of anything that extends runnable.  It means I have a queue who components are all of the same type, and that type extends runnable.   This is why the .add() method on such objects gives you compile errors.  The compiler can't tell what the actual type will be.